# Getting Bundle [] in Eclipse of all the bundles

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I am writing an application that uses Equinox as my OSGi framework.  I am trying to discover all of the bundles that are known at the time that my bundle is registered.  I attempted to use the following line to retrieve all of the available bundles.  However,

EclipseStarter.getSystemBundleContext().getBundles();

gives me a warning of...

Discouraged access: The method getSystemBundleContext() from the type EclipseStarter is not accessible due to restriction on required library D:\java\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar

What is the proper usage to get a list of all of the available bundles within the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your own bundle context as an entry point instead of the EclipseStarter - in your plugin activator:

```
start(BundleContext context)
{
  context.getBundles();  // what you want
}
```

Look at the `Plugin` cans `AbstractUIPlugin` classes if you don't know about them.
If you really need singleton access, your plugin is probably one - feel free to expose `YourPlugin.getInstance().getBundleContext()`.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried it - but it would be consistent with OSGi/Eclipse)